# getting error when trying to set custom BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, adt, baseadapter

I have just built a new class that extends BaseAdapter. I believe that I have set up everything correctly however, when i attempt to set my adapter inside the fragment I would like to use it in I am getting the following error:

The constructor HomeBase(Home) is undefined

HomeBase is the name of the class that I built.

here is the constructor for the  BaseAdapter(I would add the whole class but it is rather long):

```
// constructor call
HomeBase(Context c){

    context=c;

    list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();

    Resources res = c.getResources();
    String [] title;                            // temporary storage array for titles
    title = res.getStringArray(R.id.title);     // gets string array title and temporarily stores it in title[]

    String [] invites;                          // temporary storage array for titles
    invites = res.getStringArray(R.id.description);         // gets string array invites and temporarily stores it in invites[]

    int[] images = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5, R.drawable.img6, R.drawable.img8, 
            R.drawable.img9, R.drawable.img10, R.drawable.img11};   // get images and store them into an array


    // Loop to insert data from the different arrays into their respective single row objects, and those objects into the ArrayList list
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {

        list.add(new SingleRow (title[i], invites[i], images[i] ));

    }

}
```

this is the object that is used to populate the ArrayList list

public class SingleRow {

```
String title;
String description;
int image;

SingleRow(String title, String description, int image){

    this.title=title;
    this.description=description;
    this.image=image;

}
```

}

aaand here is the onCreate() method from the fragment that is going to use the BaseAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    list=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    list.setAdapter(new HomeBase(this));
    Log.v(HOME, "onCreate() was called");

}
```

I'm learning about all things Android now, and would appreciate any helpful suggestions.

Thanks,

James

Comment: I did here it is again:  Description Resource Path Location Type
The constructor HomeBase(Home) is undefined Home.java /DevEditionII/src/com/amicus/deveditionii line 43 Java Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your piece where you are putting your adapter inherit from `ListFragment`

```
@Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Initially there is no data 
    setEmptyText("No Data Here");

    // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
    mAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity());
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Or if in a `Fragment`, move your code as below:

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, container, false);

      list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
      list.setAdapter(new HomeBase(getActivity()));
      Log.v(HOME, "onCreate() was called");

      return view;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly!!  The class that will be using the adapter extends Fragment. I moved the code into the onCreateView() method but I am still getting the error: The constructor HomeBase(Home) is undefined

Comment: change this `list.setAdapter(new HomeBase(this));`to  `list.setAdapter(new HomeBase(getActivity()));`, Already correct in my answer above!

Comment: Thanks, using getActivity() solved my error, however now I am wrestling with a null pointer exception. I'm having a pretty tough time tracking it down.

Comment: ok I've found out where the exception is being thrown but I'm not sure how to solve it. It's in the onCreate(): 
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
  list=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list_view);
  list.setAdapter(new HomeBase(getActivity()));
  Log.v(HOME, "onCreate() was called");
  
 }
 it's the line I bring the listView from xml and assign it to the list object using: getView().findViewByID(R.id.list_view);

Comment: 07-23 13:01:55.897: W/dalvikvm(6663): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
07-23 13:01:55.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6663): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 13:01:55.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6663): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 13:01:55.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6663):  at com.amicus.deveditionii.Home.onCreate(Home.java:45)
07-23 13:01:55.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6663):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
07-23 13:01:55.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6663):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904.........

Comment: André Thanks bunch for your help, your original answer was correct!! The NPE was due to another piece of my code. Using getActivity() instead of this was the right solution.